# Client.Error.MessageSend problem with Flex/BlazeDS on JBoss

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, jboss, blazeds

I'm developing a Flex 3.4 app that interops with a Java EE backend running on a JBoss-4.2.2 server, through the most recent release of BlazeDS. When I ran the Flex app from Flash Builder 4 beta 2 on Tomcat, everything was fine, the Flex app was able to make the remote call needed. But my production environment is on JBoss, and when I moved the app to JBoss (with services-config.xml updated to fit JBoss), the Flex app keeps complaining Client.Error.MessageSend upon remote calls.
At first, when I manually deployed the app to JBoss, the faultDetail was `"Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048 ... "`; later I tried to run the app from Flash Builder, and then faultDetail became `"Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion"`.

In services-config.xml, under `<security>`, was:

```
<login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="Tomcat"/>
```

when moving to JBoss, I updated it to:

```
<login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="JBoss"/>
```

I have a crossdomain.xml placed in JBoss' deploy folder, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
    SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"> 
    <cross-domain-policy> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

But looks like it doesn't work. I've also tried to put crossdomain.xml in deploy/xxxxx.war folder, and the problem remains.

I'm using http://, not https://, so I guess it's not about security channel.

Tried to search for a solution, but most solutions were PHP related, which wasn't really helpful. Any one got any clues?

Comment: Please be careful with those crossdomain.xml files.  They can open your site up to some serious security vulnerabilities.  See an article I wrote called "How Bad Crossdomain Policies Expose Protected Data to Malicious Applications" for more details:
http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2009/11/08/how-bad-crossdomain-policies-expose-protected-data-to-malicious-applications/

Comment: Did you check the JBoss log output (in $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/log/)? Are there any error messages? Try setting the log level for BlazeDS to "Debug", if there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<login-command class="**flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand**" server="Tomcat"/>
```

Where the class indicates that security is of tomcat you should change it to a class that implements the interface **flex.messaging.security.LoginCommand** or any security interface blaze.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse to http://your.application.root/crossdomain.xml, does the file load? The simplest configuration is to put the file at the root of the domain.

Comment: Yep, I can access crossdomain.xml from `http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/`.

Comment: It sounds like you've resolved the cross domain issue then. You're now receiving only the NetConnection.Call.BadVersion error?